# Power Button or volume button trigger for notification service using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am a student working on kinda SOS app in flutter. i am stuck on a feature piece of code. When i press the power button for like 3 second or double tap the power button instead of showing the power off feature it should return a boolean that the button was hold for 3-5 seconds or pressed twice and based on that an alert notification will be generated from flutter app.

The feature should work when the app is in foreground, background and screen_off mode, the process should be through method channel or only android native code might work too for me i'll handle the rest.
i am a beginner i worked a lot but couldn't find or end up with a possible solution so if it is possible kindly help me if not provide me an answer so that i can answer why this feature was not implemented in my app.

Tried to find out solution through chat gpt because i don't have knowledge on android native because i started to work directly on flutter.

Comment: This may help you . https://pub.dev/packages/volume_watcher